# How to reload a tree view

Tags: treeview, fuelux

I want to change my datasource and re-render the tree. What would be the best way to do this? I see no 'reload' method on a data source for the treeview. Even if I keep the datasource the same, I want to reload my tree since data may have changed server side.

Comment: Any progress on this topic? I have the same problem!

Comment: I think that fuel UX is done and finished. Time to move on to a better set of tools I think... Trees are hard, and this gang must've released on a "just for us anyway" basis...